# LINQ query for many-to-many senf-reference table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have 2 EF models:

```
    public class Medicament
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string InternationalName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<MedicamentMedicaments> MedicamentMedicamentses { get; set; }
}

public class MedicamentMedicaments
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid MedicamentId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid AnalogId { get; set; }

    public Medicament Medicament { get; set; }
    public Medicament Analog { get; set; }
}
```

For example MedicamentMedicaments content:

- | MedicamentId | AnalogId |
- | 1            | 5        |
- | 5            | 3        |

I want to receive medicament analogs by medicament id with LINQ query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:

```
var query = from medicament in Db.Medicaments
            where medicament.Id == medId
            from mm in Db.MedicamentMedicamentses
            where medicament.Id == mm.MedicamentId || medicament.Id == mm.AnalogId
            select medicament.Id == mm.MedicamentId ? mm.Analog : mm.Medicament;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Analog> result = yourDbContext.MedicamentMedicaments.Where(t => t.MedicamentId == yourMedicamentId).Select(t => t.Analog).ToList()
```

or

```
 List<Analog> result = yourDbContext.Medicament.SelectMany(t => t.MedicamentMedicamentses).Where(t => t.MedicamentId == yourMedicamentId).Select(t => t.Analog).ToList()
```

or

```
 List<Analog> result = yourDbContext.Medicament.Where(t => t.Id == yourMedicamentId).SelectMany(t => t.MedicamentMedicamentses).Select(t => t.Analog).ToList()
```

Comment: It doesn`t work in my case, because Analog in MedicamentMedicaments can be stored in MedicamentId or AnalogId columns